# Python: How to plot counts of values grouped by two columns?

Tags: python, plot, group-by, categorical-data

I have some data grouped by two columns, with a count column:

```
  Category  Subcategory  Count
0        1            1     10
1        1            2     15
2        1            3     16
3        2            1      2
4        2            2      8
5        2            3     12
6        3            1     33
7        3            3     23
8        4            2      3
9        5            1      2
```

I would like to plot a clustered column chart based on the above data.
Not all categories contain all subcategories, so for these the plot should show 0. I would like to show values as counts of subcategory within a category, as percentage of the category.

Here is an example chart that Has 2 categories and multiple subcategories as separate clusters. I would like to achieve a similar result.

[image: x]

https://imge.to/i/AVUiY

Additional question: is it possible to get a break in the scale at the Y axis, so that the outlier columns (high values) become smaller, and the small values become more visible?

Answer (score 0):

I hard coded a few things just to get right to the plotting, so first you will want to create what I have called "cat1"-"cat5" from your columns of data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
n_groups = 3  #number of subcategories
cat1 = (10,15,16)
cat2 = (2,8,12)
cat3 = (33,0,23)
cat4 = (0,3,0)
cat5 = (2,0,0)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.1

rects1 = plt.bar(index, cat1, bar_width, label='1')
rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, cat2, bar_width, label='2')
rects3 = plt.bar(index + 2*bar_width, cat3, bar_width, label='3')
rects4 = plt.bar(index + 3*bar_width, cat4, bar_width, label='4')
rects5 = plt.bar(index + 4*bar_width, cat5, bar_width, label='5')

plt.xlabel('Subcategory')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Count by Category')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('1', '2', '3'))
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

To answer your second question check out the brokenaxes package: https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for this. However, in my real dataset I have as many as 12 subcategories, so I think I would be happier with a solution that is not hard coded. Thank you for the brokenaxes link!

Comment: Okay, I will see if I can include a method to get those too. What form is your current data in? Is it in like a pandas data frame?